# Use Common Table Expressions with pgr_TSP

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I have a query that uses a handful of CTEs to return a generated set of points. The actual query is more complicated, but the following will do as an example:

```sql
WITH geom AS (
    SELECT unnest('{
        POINT(-113.3997627 53.5721641), 
        POINT(-113.4037653 53.452761),
        POINT(-113.7066278 53.4571305),
        POINT(-113.7860125 53.5788978)
    }'::TEXT[]) AS point
    ORDER BY 1
),
points AS (
    SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ())::int AS id, point::geometry AS point
    FROM geom
)
SELECT *
FROM points;
```

I would like to use these points in the travelling salesperson problem function, but I haven't been able to make a simple query that achieves this.
Using the `pgr_tsp` function at the end of the query fails with at `relation "points" does not exist` error:

```sql
WITH geom AS (
    SELECT unnest('{
        POINT(-113.3997627 53.5721641), 
        POINT(-113.4037653 53.452761),
        POINT(-113.7066278 53.4571305),
        POINT(-113.7860125 53.5788978)
    }'::TEXT[]) AS point
    ORDER BY 1
),
points AS (
    SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ())::int AS id, point::geometry AS point
    FROM geom
)
SELECT seq, id1, id2, round(cost::numeric, 2) AS cost
FROM pgr_tsp('SELECT id, ST_X(point) AS x, ST_Y(point) AS y FROM points', 1);
```

Moving the entire query into the first parameter of the function seems to work, but I would need to either duplicate the CTE expressions outside of the function or store them in a temporary table to join them in the resulting order:

```sql
SELECT seq, id1, id2, round(cost::numeric, 2) AS cost
FROM pgr_tsp($$
    WITH geom AS (
        SELECT unnest('{
            POINT(-113.3997627 53.5721641), 
            POINT(-113.4037653 53.452761),
            POINT(-113.7066278 53.4571305),
            POINT(-113.7860125 53.5788978)
        }'::TEXT[]) AS point
        ORDER BY 1
    ),
    points AS (
        SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER ())::int AS id, point::geometry AS point
        FROM geom
    )
    SELECT id, ST_X(point) AS x, ST_Y(point) AS y
    FROM points
$$, 1);
```

Is there any workaround for what I am trying to achieve, or should I use a transaction with temporary table?

I am using psql9.5, postgis2.2.1, and pgrouting 2.1.0. Yes, I am planning on updating them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A third option (beside duplicating the CTE and using a TEMP table) would be to use a function to generate the content. You can then call this function from `pgr_...` or from a regular query. If it costly to generate the content, make the function [`stable`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-volatility.html) and do your join **and** the call to `pgr_...` in a single statement.

On a side note, calling `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()` without an `order by` clause is wrong if you expect to generate the content (either from a CTE, a function or else) multiple times. There is absolutely no guarantee that the rows will come in the same order each time.

Comment: In my actual query I have the `OVER` statement sorting the points by `ST_X` and `ST_Y`, thank you for that note though.
I should be able to put my CTEs into a function, I will try that and thank you for responding.

Comment: This worked! I made the function `IMMUTABLE` because it will always return the same result for given inputs, and joined the new function's `id` column with the `id2` column from the `pgr_tsp` call.